# Configure Elmah to use existing stored procedure/tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, elmah

We have a system that already has a table and some stored procedures used for logging (Oracle). I am currently working on another system which is going to use the same database, but does not have a system for logging errors yet.

I read that Elmah was an easy to use system, and have tried to set it up, but it seems that it by default tries to use tables and procedures that can be made the scripts that came with the Elmah download.

So, my question is, is it possible to configure Elmah to use myStoredProcedure, and if it is, how do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the stored procedure that Elmah calls, and the parameters that get sent, you would have to [download the source code](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/list), edit the [OracleErrorLog.cs](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/OracleErrorLog.cs) file, and recompile. If you feel comfortable with that, it shouldn't be too hard.

Alternatively, you could just edit the [Oracle.sql](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/Oracle.sql) script to alter the built-in Elmah packages to point to your own tables.